# how to bind data to listbox in wp7

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, linq-to-objects

i am binding data to listbox in wp7

here is the code

```
              <ListBox x:Name="list_budget" Width="440">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Name="txtname" Text="{Binding category}"></TextBlock>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

//class function

```
    public string[] jinal;

    public void  budgetcategorywise()
    {

        var q = from shoppingItem p in db.Item1
                group p by new { p.category_name } into g
                select new { category = g.Key, total = g.Sum(p => p.total_amt) `enter code here`}.ToString();

      jinal = q.toarray();
}
```

//coding

```
        list_budget.ItemsSource = App.Viewmod.jinal;
```

now,the error is query is ok result is perfact but i am not able to bind the data to listbox.

Comment: Your Listbox xaml code is not clear, edit the question with proper code. Also give the code of jinal class, what members does it contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code sample:

1. Please make sure `budgetcategorywise()` is called before you do the binding
2. Please change your binding to:

   ```
    <TextBlock Name="txtname" Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
   ```

The reason for this second change is that your code uses a `ToString()` in the Linq list generation - which means that the class with its `category` field is flattened in a string represenation.

---

If you wish to keep the category field in your binding then use a class for your list items like:

```
   public class MyListItem
   {
       public string category { get;set; }
       public double total { get;set; }
   }

   public List<MyListItem> jinal;

   public void  budgetcategorywise()
   {

        var q = from shoppingItem p in db.Item1
                group p by new { p.category_name } into g
                select new MyListItem() { category = g.Key, total = g.Sum(p => p.total_amt) };

      jinal = q.ToList();
   }
```

Comment: yeah thankx for help. but result is not that i want. result is like {category ={category_name = dairy},total =150}

Comment: i want the result like dairy  150 in list box

Comment: in that case use 2 textboxes inside a stackpanel or grid, or use a custom converter - it might be worth looking through some of the tutorials on http://create.msdn.com